# Pasar un id por post en formulario

Tags: laravel-6

el problema es que al borrar un empleado de mi lista 
(url(127.0.0.1:8080/empleados), mi url queda como 
(url(127.0.0.1:8080/empleados/id), el id es el 
número del respectivo usuario que borro. así que mi duda es como hacer 
que al borrar el empleado, se quede en 127.0.0.1:8080/empleados 
solamente, sin mostrar el id. 
Espero haberme explicado bien, muchas gracias!
ESTOY HACIENDO UNA LLAMADA POR GUZZLE HACIA LA API. por eso uso esto en el destroy:

```
$response = $client->delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/borrar/'.$id);



//este es el código que tengo en mi index.

<form method="post" action="{‌{url('/empleados/'.$empleado->id)}}">
{‌{ csrf_field() }}
{‌{ method_field('DELETE') }}
<button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿está seguro?');" >Borrar</button>
</form>

//este es mi controlador donde borro el Empleado.
public function destroy($id)
    {   
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/borrar/'.$id);
        $stream = $response->getBody();
        $contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
        $datos['empleados']=json_decode($contents);
        return view('empleados.index',$datos);
    }

//esta es mi ruta Api.
Route::get('/user/borrar/{id}','ApiController@DeleEmpleado');

/*también intenté pasar el id del empleado ($empleado->id) como tipo hidden
pero lo sigue mandando :(*/

<form method="post" action="{{url('/empleados/'.$empleado->id)}}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ $empleado->id }}" name="id" /> 
   <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿está seguro?');" >Borrar</button>
</form>

//en la imagen se ve el id del empleado que acabo de borrar.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FRXQ.png

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de  usar `Route::get` puedes usar `Route::delete` y allí unicamente retornar un mensaje de que el usuario fue eliminado.

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $client = Client::find($id);
    if (empaty($client)) {
       // Mensaje de que no existe
    } 
    $client->delete();
    // retornas el mensaje de que fue eliminado.
}
```

Tu ruta de quedaría asi:

```
    Route::delete('/user/borrar/{id}','ApiController@DeleEmpleado');
```

Comment: Hola, buenas! el tema es que estoy conectando mi web a otro proyecto( a una Api), por eso mi destroy es así, hago la llamada con guzzle. 

public function destroy($id)
    {   
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/borrar/'.$id);
        $stream = $response->getBody();
        $contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
        $datos['empleados']=json_decode($contents);
        return view('empleados.index',$datos);
    }

por eso le debo mandar el id por 
$response = $client->get('ruta'.$id);
gracias